# MySQL COUNT query results in 1 always

Tags: php, mysql, count

I'm wondering why my MySQL `COUNT(*)` query always results in `->num_rows` to be equal `1`.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM u11_users");
print $result->num_rows; // prints 1
```

Whereas fetching "real data" from the database works fine.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM u11_users");
print $result->num_rows; // prints the correct number of elements in the table
```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count() is an aggregate function which means it returns just one row that contains the actual answer.  You'd see the same type of thing if you used a function like max(id); if the maximum value in a column was 142, then you wouldn't expect to see 142 records but rather a single record with the value 142.  Likewise, if the number of rows is 400 and you ask for the count(*), you will not get 400 rows but rather a single row with the answer: 400.

So, to get the count, you'd run your first query, and just access the value in the first (and only) row.

By the way, you should go with this count(*) approach rather than querying for all the data and taking `$result->num_rows;` because querying for all rows will take far longer since you're pulling back a bunch of data you do not need.

Answer (score 6):

Because `Count(*)` returns just one line with the number of rows.

Example:
Using `Count(*)` the result's something like the following.

```
array('COUNT(*)' => 20);
echo $result['COUNT(*)']; // 20
```

[**Reference**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html)

Answer (score 3):

It *should* return one row*. To get the count you need to:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM u11_users");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
print $row["C"];
```

<sub>* since you are using an aggregate function and not using `GROUP BY`</sub>

Answer (score 2):

that's why `COUNT` exists, it always returns one row with number of selected rows

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html